# Open company-domain links in Opera Browser and everything else in Chrome Browser to separate my Personal and Corporate lives

Tags: windows-10, browser, url

I use the same PC (Windows 10) for work and personal purpose. The company I work for has some services running under its own domain (something.COMPANY.com) and some under other domains via cloud services (COMPANY.zoom.us ; COMPANY.app.box.com ; ...).

I would like to be able to create a list of domains (something.COMPANY.com ; COMPANY.zoom.us ; COMPANY.app.box.com ; ...) and use them as a FilterList. When I click any link, anywhere on my computer (in websites, in Outlook, on my desktop shortcuts, ...) the required solution should decide if that link has any part matching the **FilterList**, if yes the link should open in a specific browser (in my case it is Opera). Any other links, not matching the FilterList should open in the default browser as normal (Google Chrome in my case).

This way I would be able to separate my Corporate life from my Personal life, having a browser dedicated for the corporate stuff. I would use this browser to remember my corporate passwords (only), store my corporate bookmarks (only), store my corporate credit card information (only), maybe even have specific extensions relevant only for my corporate work installed in it.

The idea is to keep my two lives completely separated on a browser level.

Answer (score 1):

https://browserchooser2.com/ is your friend here (hopefully, I haven't used it for a while).

You can specify a default browser and any specific domains or URLs (based on wildcards etc) to open in a different browser. You set Browser Chooser as your default web browser in Windows, and it handles everything for you.

You can even have it prompt you each time for what browser you want to open.

Answer (score 0):

There is no software I know of that does this.
You will need to write your own,
then set your program up as the handler of all URLs, and it would be the
one to invoke the indicated browser.

This is a lot of work that may not justify the required investment of
your time, but here goes.

Below are some untested suggestions. You will need to still do some
research of your own to arrive at a complete solution.

The simplest programming language to use would be the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

You would need something like the following untested AutoHotkey script:

```
#NoEnv
domains = COMPANY.zoom.us,COMPANY.app.box.com
DEFAULT_BROWSER := "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
ALTERNATE_BROWSER := "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
url = %1%
pos := RegExMatch(%url%, "://\K([^/:\s]+)", match)
if match1 in domains {
    Run %ALTERNATE_BROWSER% %url%
} else {
    Run %DEFAULT_BROWSER% %url%
}
Return
```

I suggest to test the script by modifying it to use a test URL as the
value of the variable `url`.

Once the script is in its final form, you will need to
[Convert a Script to an EXE](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe)
by using the included utility `Ahk2Exe`.
You would find instructions on doing that in the link.

You would finally need to modify the registry to use the compiled `.exe`
as the handler for at least the HTTPS protocol.
This requires registry work, and you will find as example the article
[Register a portable browser and make it the default](https://kolbi.cz/blog/2019/01/27/register-a-portable-browser-and-make-it-the-default/?sfw=pass1649683005).

Answer (score 0):

I tried browserchooser2, but wasn't able to configure it in a way, that it stays hidden and execute in the backrgound.

After inspecting multiple alternatives at https://alternativeto.net/software/browser-chooser-2

I finally settled with **BrowserSelect**
https://github.com/zumoshi/BrowserSelect

BrowserSelect can filter my corporate links. The manual is here for setting filters:
https://github.com/zumoshi/BrowserSelect/blob/master/help/filters.md

It explicitly lists, what I am after :)

> Examples
> open all websites in firefox but companywebsite.com in IE:
>
> - rule 1: * -> Firefox
> - rule 2: *.companywebsite.com -> IE